# Men go to another planet, turn into crystal beings

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a story from an anthology from the 1950s, where men were on another planet and they saw some crystal beings in the sky. The humans might walk through a maze or some cause and they gradually change into those crystal life forms.

Comment: If you get a helpful answer to your question, you can [accept](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it by clicking on the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

**I read a story from an anthology from the 1950s,**

The story is ["Environment"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?56995) by [Chester S. Geier](http://www.sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/geier_chester_s), first published in [*Astounding Science Fiction*, May 1944](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?57591+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Astounding_v33n03_1944-05_dtsg0318#page/n159/mode/2up). The anthology is [Groff Conklin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groff_Conklin)'s [*Omnibus of Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?24853); an abridged edition was published in Britain as [*Strange Adventures in Science Fiction*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?33464).

**where men were on another planet**

> "Deserted!" he whispered. "Deserted—but why?"
>
> Jon Gaynor turned as Wade Harlan emerged from the lock. The two glanced at each other, then, in mutual perplexity, their eyes turned to the dreaming city. After a long moment, Wade Harlan spoke.
>
> "Jon, I was thinking—Perhaps this isn't the right planet. Perhaps . . . perhaps old Mark Gaynor and the Purists never landed here at all—"
>
> Jon Gaynor shook his brown head slowly. He was a tall, lean figure in a tight-fitting, slate-gray overall. "I've considered that possibility, Wade. No—this is the place, all right. Everything checks against the data given in that old Bureau of Expeditions report. Seven planets in the system—this the second planet. And this world fits perfectly the description given in the report—almost a second Earth. Then there's the sun. Its type, density, rate of radiation, spectrum—all the rest—they check, too."

**and they saw some crystal beings in the sky.**

> Gaynor straightened with purpose. "We'll learn which is the answer. I'm not leaving until we do. We'll—" Gaynor broke off, his eyes jerking toward the sky. High up and far away in the blue, something moved, a vast swarm of objects too tiny for identification. They soared and circled, dipped and swooped like birds. And as the two men from another planet watched, sounds drifted down to them—sweet, crystalline tinklings and chimings, so infinitely faint that they seemed to be sensed rather than heard.

**The humans might walk through a maze or some cause and they gradually change**

> Instruction followed application, and in a very few days, Gaynor and Harlan moved on. Thus they went, from unit to unit, and always the wall paintings pointed out the way.
>
> The sun rose and the sun set, and the city dreamed on. And always high in the sky, the crystal creatures circled and soared, tinkling and chiming. The days passed gently, mere wraiths of sunlight.
>
> The machines grew larger, more intricate, ever more difficult of solution. Each was a new test upon the growing knowledge of Gaynor and Harlan. And each test was harder than the last, for the wall paintings no longer pointed out the way, but merely hinted now.

**into those crystal life forms.**

> The beings who once had been Gaynor and Harlan narleened the paintings on the wall of the Temple, gazed upon them with this new, all-embracing sense which went far beyond the limited realms of mere vision—so that almost the paintings spoke to them and they answered back. They narleened the paintings.
>
> Their every question was answered—for all eternity.
>
> And thus it came about, after a time, that two great, faceted crystals emerged from the doorway of the Temple, and lifted, pulsing with a vibrant new life, flashing in rainbow splendor, into the sky. Higher, they lifted, and higher, chiming and tinkling, soaring to join the others of their kind.
>
> The sun shone brightly in the sky. High and far away in the blue, glittering clouds of crystal creatures darted and danced, sending wave after exquisite wave of crystalline melody upon the gentle shores of air. Among them now were two who had still to learn the intricacies of flight.
>
> And the city dreamed on.
>
> A perfect environment, the city. Ideal for the inquisitive humanoid.