# Astronauts land on a deserted planet with an interactive museum

Tags: story-identification

My memory is vauge: astronauts land on a strange alien deserted planet and find a structure housing interactive exhibits offering sight and sound and feel .. and other senses things to experience and find that it is training and indoctrinating the ships crew.

Comment: Could you please add more [details](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info)? Is this a film, a book, a series, a comic? When did you read this? Which country?  How many years ago? What language? Any other details you can remember?

Comment: What format was this--movie, TV, novel, short story, comic? What language was it in, and when did you remember it from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear. Please refer to [story-identification asking guidelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info) and the [ask] page, and then [edit] your question appropriately.

Comment: With it being multiple astronauts, not http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153721/need-to-identitify-a-short-story-about-an-astronaut-stranded-alone-on-a-planet-t?

Comment: I think there was a _Star Trek Voyager_ episode with this premise.

Comment: Possibly Clifford Simak's novellette [*Jackpot*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45927) first published in *Galaxy* Oct, 1956. "Shoestring salvagers hit the jackpot when they discover a galactic library, but soon learn a little knowledge is a dangerous thing." (Wikipedia) "The sticks were recordings that packed in not only sight and sound, but stimuli for all the other senses. They did the job so well that anyone subjected to their influence felt that he was part of the environment they presented. He stepped into the picture and became a part of it. He was really there." (excerpt)

Comment: Could it be ["Environment"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121434/men-go-to-another-planet-turn-into-crystal-beings) by Chester S. Geier?

Comment: My apologies for being vague.  It was a short story, maybe longer but not a novel.  I would often spend hours in a library reading anything in sci fi that I could get my hands on.  I'm guessing late 1950s.  Over the years I continued but was distracted by family, Engineering School etc.  TV included Truman Bradley's Science Fiction Theater etc.